# "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting an error in a button click as "uncaught range error maximum call stack". Why I am getting this error?

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at camelCase (jquery-latest.js:3989)
    at Data.get (jquery-latest.js:4070)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-latest.js:8247)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-latest.js:8328)
    at Function.each (jquery-latest.js:354)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-latest.js:189)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery-latest.js:8327)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (personalize.hooks.js:19)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-latest.js:5184)
```

these are my codes

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChangePwd" CssClass="btn-primary" Style="display: none;" OnClientClick="ChangePassword(); return false;"
                                UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="<%$ Resources:rChangePwd %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:rChangePwd %>" />




function ChangePassword() {
            $("#columnSelectorTabset1").text('');
            var url = strPublicmap + "/EN/AnswerLinkDotNet/SoHoXi/Profile/XiUpdatePassword.aspx?isFromPage=AddEditContact&UserName=" + $("#txtXtremeID").val() + "&userEmailId=" + $("#txtEmail").val() + "&NeedHidden=1";
            $("#columnSelectorTabset1").append('<iframe src=' + url + ' style="width:950px;height:340px;border:0px;"></iframe>');
            $('#divUpdatePassword').message({
                title: '<%= HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(GetLocalResourceObject("rUpdatePassword")) %>',
                width: 950,
                height: 340,
                modal: true,
                showTitleClose: false,
                beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
                    if (charCode == 27) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                buttons: [{
                    id: 'CloseButton',
                    text: "<%= GetLocalResourceObject("Close") %>",
                    isDefault: false
                }]
            });

            $(".dialogButtonBar").css("display", "none");
         }
```

Its a modal box . and it should be display with the button click.